# Two clock domains in the same procces

Tags: vhdl

The module clock is CLK = 120 Mhz.
The milliseconds counter clock is MS_CLK = 100 Mhz.
I count milliseconds

```vhdl
constant TICKS_FOR_1MS : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := X"000186A0"; --100 Mhz
process (MS_CLK)
begin

    if (rising_edge(MS_CLK)) then
        
         if (count_reset= '1') then
             ticks_counter <= (others => '0');
             ms_counter <= (others => '0');
         else
            ticks_counter <= ticks_counter + '1';
            if (ticks_counter = TICKS_FOR_1MS) then
                  ticks_counter <= (others => '0');
                  ms_counter <= ms_counter + '1';
            end if;
        end if;
 
    end if;   
end process;
```

The problem is - the signal **count_reset** is changed in another process that clocked with CLK.
How to synchronize those signals?

**EDIT:**

What about synchronous reset?

```vhdl
process(CLK, RST)
begin
    if RST = '1' then
        ticks_counter <= (others => '0');
        ms_counter <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
        ticks_counter <= ticks_counter + '1';
        if (ticks_counter = TICKS_FOR_1MS) then
            ticks_counter <= (others => '0');
            ms_counter <= ms_counter + '1';
        end if;
    end if;
end process;
```

Should it work?

Comment: Use a synchroniser (typically a "dual FF synchroniser" ) on EVERY asynchronous input.

Comment: can you kindly point to some example? I don't understand how to implement the   synchronizer.

Comment: what about synchronous  reset - 
process(CLK, RST)
begin

    if RST = '1' then
        ticks_counter <= (others => '0');
  ms_counter <= (others => '0');
    elsif rising_edge(CLK) then
        ticks_counter <= ticks_counter + '1';
        if (ticks_counter = TICKS_FOR_1MS) then
        ticks_counter <= (others => '0');
        ms_counter <= ms_counter + '1';
    end if; 
    end if; 
end process;

Should it work?

Comment: I have [edit]ed your question with your new idea. Please do it yourself the next time. -- What you propose is not a **synchronous** reset, it is asynchronous. You need to put the `if RST = '1' ...` into the block with `rising_edge()`. -- If you do this, make sure that the signal `RST` is active for a long enough time. It will work.

Comment: That's the problem - reset signal modified in the process clocked with 120Mhz and processed in the one clocked with 100Mhz. It would be missed.

Comment: Even in asynchronous mode.